# How Remove Owner From Google Search Console Property?

Tags: google-search-console

I want to remove myself from the Google Search Console Property, however I am the owner (Verified owner) of that property and also providing access to other person. Other Owner can remove me as I am the main owner. Please Help Me To Remove Myself. When other remove me blow Error shows:

> Failed to remove Access: can't remove a verified owner.

[image: Remove first Account]
[image: Error Show on Removing]

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7687615?hl=en

> If you are taking over a site from another owner, after you verify
> ownership you can unverify previous owners by removing their
> verification token (for example, removing the HTML tag from the site,
> for HTML-tag-verified owners)
>
> To remove a verified owner
>
> If all verified owners are removed, then all remaining users will lose
> access to the property after a grace period. Data for the property
> will continue to be collected, but nobody will have access to it until
> someone verifies ownership of the property.
>
> You must delete all tokens used to verify a specific user's ownership
> of the property. A user might use multiple methods to verify their
> property.
>
> Determine the verification method(s) used for the owner. Be sure to
> determine the unique token value used for the user that you wish to
> remove.
>
> Remove all verification tokens for that user for the property. For
> instance, if "HTML Tag" is listed, you must remove the HTML  tag
> for that person from the site. If "HTML File" is listed, you must
> remove the HTML verification file for that person from the site. If
> you don't remove all verification tokens for a user, they can be
> reverified as an owner using any remaining tokens.
>
> **HTML file upload:** Look for the HTML file associated with the user at the root location for your site. The file will have a long
> alphanumeric name, and a single line of text that includes the string
> "google-site-verification". Remove this tag. Make sure that you remove
> only the tag assigned to the person you wish to remove.
>
> **HTML tag:** Look in the page source of your homepage for the user's tag, which looks something like this: . You must remove
> the tag from the page source. Make sure that you remove only the tag
> associated with the user that you wish to remove.
>
> **Domain name provider:** You must find and remove the DNS record associated with the user.
>
> **Google Analytics account:** In order to permanently disable this verification mechanism for this user, you must either switch Google
> Analytics accounts for this site, or else revoke edit rights given to
> this person in the Google Analytics account for this site. To
> determine which Google Analytics account is used for this site, look
> at the rendered source of the page (in Chrome, right-click and choose
> Inspect), and search for "UA-" or "G-" in the page code, which should
> correspond to your Google Analytics account.
>
> **Google Tag Manager account:** In order to permanently disable this verification method for this user, you must either switch Google Tag
> Manager accounts used on this site, or remove the person's Publish or
> Admin permission in the associated Google Tag Manager account.
>
> **Google Sites/Blogger account:** The owner of a Google Site or Blogger website will always have access to the associated property in
> Search Console. To completely remove access, the owner of the Google
> Site or Blogger website must be switched (because a Google Site or
> Blogger account must always have one and only one owner).
>
> **Google Domains account:** Remove the user as administrator from the associated Google Domains account.
>
> After removing the former owner's tokens from the site, open the Users
> and permissions page.
>
> Click Unverify next to the owner's name to unverify the unwanted
> owner. The owner's verification token must be gone, or else the
> unverify request will fail. (Even if you don't unverify ownership
> using the Users and permissions page, Search Console will eventually
> notice the removed token, and that owner will then lose access to the
> Search Console property.)